# Conditionally display text in print pdf

Tags: java, css, pdf

I want to conditionally display "[REMAINDER OF PAGE INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK]" on a print pdf.
I am using below to do a page break after the text. But I couldn't find a solution to not to display this text if a page has only this text and not any other text. In that scenario we don't need to display this text or have any page break. Thanks for your time.

```
<p style="text-align:center;page-break-after: always;">
             [REMAINDER OF PAGE INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK]
</p>
```